# options using getopt in c

Tags: c, filenames, command-line-arguments, getopt

I want the put a sub-option in a string so that I can use it as a file name for reading a file:

```
char *nvalue = NULL;
char *dvalue = NULL;
char *input = NULL;
char inputfilename[] = "\"";
int ar;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   while ((ar = getopt(argc, argv, "hn:d:i:")) != -1)
      switch (ar)
      {
         case 'h':
            printf("something");
            break; /* added */
         case 'n':
            nvalue = optarg;
            if (isdigit(nvalue))
               stop = atoi(nvalue);
            else
               printf("something\n");
            break; /* added */
         case 'd':
            dvalue = optarg;
            if (!strcmp(dvalue, "FCFS")   || !strcmp(dvalue, "SSTF") ||
                !strcmp(dvalue, "C-SCAN") || !strcmp(dvalue, "LOOK"))
               ;
            else
               printf("Invalid type of disk scheduling policy entered.\n");
            break; /* added */
         case 'i':
            input = optarg;
            strcpy(inputfilename, optarg);
            printf("Filename :%s\n", inputfilename);
            break;
      }
   /* ... */
}
```

So on the command line if I input:

```
./foobar -i hello
```

then I should be able to read the file with:

```
FILE *file = fopen(inputfilename, "r" );
```

any suggestions? answers?
thanks!

Comment: What is your problem with this code? I added breaks to switch options, declared stop variable and included appropriate files and it worked as you requested. So I do not know how can I help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.  I'm ignoring the absence of header files (assuming your code uses the correct ones so all functions have a prototype in scope before use).  I'm also reformatting your code ruthlessly but without further comment.

```
char *nvalue = NULL;
char *dvalue = NULL;
char *input = NULL;
char inputfilename[] = "\"";
```

This allocated an array of two bytes as `inputfilename`.  I hate to think what's going to happen when you use it.

```
int ar;
```

There is every reason why this variable should be local to the main function and no reason visible for it to be a global variable.  Unless you have a header declaring them, the other variables should also be `static` - assuming that you need to access their values outside of `main()` without a convenient way to pass them as locals.  Avoid global variables whenever possible.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while ((ar = getopt(argc, argv, "hn:d:i:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (ar)
        {
        case 'h':
            printf("something");
```

Oops; no `break`, so the code drops through to the `case 'n':` code.  C is not Pascal.

```
        case 'n':
            nvalue = optarg;
            if (isdigit(nvalue))
                stop = atoi(nvalue);
```

You haven't shown a declaration for `stop`.  Unless you really need the string, you can do without `nvalue`, avoiding a global variable, which is always desirable.

```
            else
                printf("something\n");
```

Another missing `break`; I'm not going to point it out again.

```
        case 'd':
            dvalue = optarg;
            if (strcmp(dvalue, "FCFS")   == 0 ||
                strcmp(dvalue, "SSTF")   == 0 ||
                strcmp(dvalue, "C-SCAN") == 0 ||
                strcmp(dvalue, "LOOK"    == 0)
            {
```

I'd suggest a comment such as `/* Nothing - dvalue is OK */`.  Or inverting the condition using De Morgan's theorem:

```
            if (strcmp(dvalue, "FCFS")   != 0 &&
                strcmp(dvalue, "SSTF")   != 0 &&
                strcmp(dvalue, "C-SCAN") != 0 &&
                strcmp(dvalue, "LOOK"    != 0)
```

You might even decide to encapsulate that test into a function which tests the value against each element of an array of codes.

```
            }
            else
                printf("Invalid type of disk scheduling policy entered.\n");
```

It would be courteous to provide a list of the acceptable values - which suddenly becomes another reason for having an array of valid values which you can use to generate the list. Very often, error messages should be reported on `stderr` (using `fprintf()`) rather than `stdout`.

```
        case 'i':
            input = optarg;
```

This assignment is sufficient.

```
            strcpy(inputfilename, optarg);
```

Unless the user types a single-character file name, you've just overflowed the `inputfilename` array.  You really didn't need to make a copy of the argument unless you're going to modify the name (for example, to add or change the extension on the name).

```
             //strcat(inputfilename,"\"");   
             printf("Filename :%s\n", inputfilename);
        }
```

You didn't include a `default` clause.  Since `ar` will be assigned the value `?` when the user-provided option is not recognized, this is normally your cue to provide a simple usage message and exit.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot. I put break in my code put i didn't put it here. duh!